# Probability of a mini game in "Mario Party 4"

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, mathematical-modeling

There's a minigame in Mario Party 4 called "Hide and Go Boom".
4 players must compete in the game.
There are 4 cannons labeled A,B,X, & Y.
3 players are "hiders", and 1 player the "seeker".

The Seeker has 3 attempts to catch everyone via lighting a fuse for one of the aforementioned cannons. (They choose 3 cannons to fire out of the 4)

What's the probability of this being the best choice from a hider's perspective, keeping in mind the following information;
-The Seeker has three attempts and the cannon they select is eliminated once it has been shot
-Hiders are not allowed to pick a new cannon or switch once they seeker begins lighting fuses
-Hiders are able to be in any combination of cannons- see below scenarios

Scenario A (everybody takes their owns cannons): A, B, X are used, Y is empty.
Scenario B (everyone jumps into one cannon) A is only used, all others remain empty
Scenario C (2 in 1, and 1 in the other)

I've taken up to differential equations but not a single probability class in my life, so I'm struggling as how to model the probability for each scenario, notably scenario C.

Comment: I'm not sure any of them have any particular special properties.  No matter what, you have a 3/4 chance of being fired, and you'd expect 2 1/4 of the hiders to be found.

Comment: If the seeker never receives any information about where the hiders are other than when they fire a cannon, then I don't think the hiders' strategy matters: the seeker is simply choosing at random, and each hider survives with a probability of 25%.